# PHP semi-random word generator

Tags: php, button, random

The following code is working. But I'd like to improve it. Basically, this page displays a random str per each categories and reloads a page when a user pushes a button. 
Can it be different so I could manage the data easier(I want to update the words library frequently). I also wonder if this is short enough for quick loading.
Thank you so much for your help in advance.

```
<!-- begin -->
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>


<?php 
#hash = random url generated from 128 chars


$words = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana'); 
$rword = rand(0,2);

$syms = array('chair', 'sofa', 'table', 'coffee table');
$rsym = rand(0,3); 

$value1 = $words[$rword];
$final1 = strtoupper($value1);

$value2 = $syms[$rsym];
$final2 = strtoupper($value2);

?>


<h2>Fruit</h2><p><?php echo $final1 = strtolower($value1); ?></p>
<h2>Furniture</h2><p><?php echo $final2 = strtolower($value2); ?></p>


<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="random.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="generate again">
</FORM>



</body>
</html>

<!-- end -->
```

Comment: This question might be a better match for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could use a database to store your words and to retrieve a random one.

Comment: Yes lots can be improved, for instance, use [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) will save you counting your words, or store words in db like jerone said, also your html is BAD!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a Database with 2 tables.

Table 1 would be `Categories`:
This would contain `Fruit,Furniture,Rivers,etc.`

Table 2 would be `Items`:
This would contain `chair,apple,sofa,orange,etc.` all associated to the correct `Categories` id.

You could then query for ALL categories and return that into a full array. You could then `foreach` your way through the array of categories and do another query set to an array of items. Once you do that you can get the length of items and do much the same as you are doing.

This is a descriptive answer to give you an idea that you should move to. Without knowledge of your exact idea and structure set I do not want to risk writing faulty code.